# Cyclomatic complexity for index is too high

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have index action in my Controller:

```
def index
  authenticate_admin!
  @users = User.paginate(per_page: 25, page: params[:page])
  if params[:list_type].to_i == 2 # => Pending mentors
    @users = @users.where(documents: { is_verified: 0 }, user_type: 0, profile_status: 1)
  elsif params[:list_type].to_i == 1 # => approved listing
    @users = @users.where(documents: { is_verified: 1 }, user_type: 0) if params[:user_type].to_i.zero? # => Mentor
    @users = @users.where(user_type: 1) if params[:user_type].to_i == 1 # => mentee
  end
  @users = @users.where('full_name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
  @users = if params[:sort].to_i == 1
    @users.order(full_name: :asc)
  else
    @users.order(id: :desc)
  end

  @users = @users.profession.where(id: params[:profession_ids]) if params[:profession_ids].present?
  @users = @users.call('age >= ?', params[:from_date]) if params[:from_date].present?
  @users = @users.call('age <= ?', params[:to_date]) if params[:to_date].present?
  @users = @users.where(gender: params[:gender]) if params[:gender].present?
  @users = @users.includes(:document)
end
```

but when I run `Rubocop` to check if my code has any `offense`.
then it returns me two errors.

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:3: C: Metrics/CyclomaticComplexity: Cyclomatic complexity for index is too high. [11/6]
  def index ...
  ^^^^^^^^^
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:5:3: C: Metrics/PerceivedComplexity: Perceived complexity for index is too high. [13/7]
  def index ...
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

So, I divide my index action to multiple actions like:

```
def index
  authenticate_admin!
  @users = User.paginate(per_page: 25, page: params[:page])
  if params[:list_type].to_i == 2 # => Pending mentors
    @users = @users.where(documents: { is_verified: 0 }, user_type: 0, profile_status: 1)
  elsif params[:list_type].to_i == 1 # => approved listing
    @users = @users.where(documents: { is_verified: 1 }, user_type: 0) if params[:user_type].to_i.zero? # => Mentor
    @users = @users.where(user_type: 1) if params[:user_type].to_i == 1 # => mentee
  end

  search
end

def search
  @users = @users.where('full_name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
  @users = if params[:sort].to_i == 1
    @users.order(full_name: :asc)
  else
    @users.order(id: :desc)
  end

  apply_filter
end

def apply_filter
  @users = @users.profession.where(id: params[:profession_ids]) if params[:profession_ids].present?
  @users = @users.call('age >= ?', params[:from_date]) if params[:from_date].present?
  @users = @users.call('age <= ?', params[:to_date]) if params[:to_date].present?
  @users = @users.where(gender: params[:gender]) if params[:gender].present?
  @users = @users.includes(:document)
end
```

Is this the right way to implement code like this or is there anything else i can do to refine my coding structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the right way to implement code like this

As long as you find the code reasonable and clear. If the `index` method is the only method in the controller, then it won't be a problem to navigate through the logic of the users search.

> is there anything else i can do to refine my coding structure

One of the options would be extracting the these two methods (or even more logic) into a separate class/file. For example, something like:

**controller**

```
def index
  authenticate_admin!
  @users = User.paginate(per_page: 25, page: params[:page])
  if params[:list_type].to_i == 2 # => Pending mentors
    @users = @users.where(documents: { is_verified: 0 }, user_type: 0, profile_status: 1)
  elsif params[:list_type].to_i == 1 # => approved listing
    @users = @users.where(documents: { is_verified: 1 }, user_type: 0) if params[:user_type].to_i.zero? # => Mentor
    @users = @users.where(user_type: 1) if params[:user_type].to_i == 1 # => mentee
  end

  @users = Users::Search.new(@users).call
end
```

**service**

```
class Users::Search
  attr_reader :params, :users

  def initialize(users, params)
    @users = users
    @params = params
  end

  def search
    users = @users.where('full_name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
    users = if params[:sort].to_i == 1
      users.order(full_name: :asc)
    else
      users.order(id: :desc)
    end

    apply_filter(users)
  end

  def apply_filter(users)
    users = users.profession.where(id: params[:profession_ids]) if params[:profession_ids].present?
    users = users.call('age >= ?', params[:from_date]) if params[:from_date].present?
    users = users.call('age <= ?', params[:to_date]) if params[:to_date].present?
    users = users.where(gender: params[:gender]) if params[:gender].present?
    users.includes(:document)
  end
end
```

And one of the advantages of the extracting is that such class is easier to test, than a controller method, which requires a request and parsing a response for every test case.